# How to implement RedisCache.class in Java Spring Boot to store a key value pair

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, redis-cache

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping()
public class AuthController extends BaseController {
    JwtProvider tokenProvider;

    RedisCache<String,UserModel> redisCache;


    @Autowired
    public AuthController(
        JwtProvider tokenProvider,
        MessageHelper messageHelper,
        ModelMapper modelMapper,
        RedisCache<String,UserPrincipalTransformerModel> redisCache
    ) {
        super(AuthController.class, messageHelper, modelMapper);

        this.userService = userService;

        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;

        this.loginTokenService = loginTokenService;

        this.companyUserService = companyUserService;

        this.apiKeyService = apiKeyService;

        this.redisCache = redisCache;
    }
```

I want to store Key value like this,
redisCache.put("string",userModel);

can anyone know how to use RedisCache.Class and instantize it, because currently I am getting a error that.

required a bean of type 'io.lettuce.core.support.caching.RedisCache' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'io.lettuce.core.support.caching.RedisCache' in your configuration.
..............
But I want to use default RedisCache.class

```
/*
 * Copyright 2020-2022 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package io.lettuce.core.support.caching;

/**
 * Interface defining common Redis Cache operations.
 *
 * @param <K> Key type.
 * @param <V> Value type.
 * @author Mark Paluch
 * @since 6.0
 */
public interface RedisCache<K, V> {

    /**
     * Retrieve a {@code value} from Redis for the given cache {@code key}.
     *
     * @param key the key whose associated value is to be returned.
     * @return the value to which this Redis cache value maps the specified key (which may be {@code null} itself), or also
     *         {@code null} if the Redis cache contains no mapping for this key.
     */
    V get(K key);

    /**
     * Associate the specified value with the specified key in this Redis cache.
     *
     * @param key the key with which the specified value is to be associated.
     * @param value the value to be associated with the specified key.
     */
    void put(K key, V value);

    /**
     * Register a invalidation {@code listener} that is notified if a key in this Redis cache expires or gets modified.
     *
     * @param listener the listener to notify.
     */
    void addInvalidationListener(java.util.function.Consumer<? super K> listener);

    /**
     * Closes this Redis cache and releases any connections associated with it. If the cache is already closed then invoking
     * this method has no effect.
     */
    void close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add redis dependencies**

Like always, Spring boot makes things easier with the help of sophisticated starter dependencies. All you have to do is to add the Redis starter.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add appropriate settings for the Redis configuration. You can skip the following if you are using Redis locally.

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=8080
```

In production you may need to add spring.redis.username and spring.redis.password based on your server.

**Enable Caching**

To enable caching support in Spring boot, first, you need to annotate the main class with @EnableCaching.

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootRedisCacheExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootRedisCacheExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Add @Cacheable annotation**

Find a long-running method and annotate it with @Cacheable. This annotation takes a value which is the cache name. And the key is a unique object to look up the value in cache later.

```
@Cacheable(value = "items", key = "#id")
public Item getItem(Integer id) {
    Item item = itemRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    logger.info("Loading data from DB {}", item);
    return item;
}
```

In this case, We used Spring Expression Language(SpEL) to pass the argument value as key.

**Add @CacheEvict annotation**
Once cached, The values stay there indefinitely. Thus, the cache abstraction will never pick updated values from the database. For this reason, you should use @CacheEvict on updates.

```
@CacheEvict(value = "items", key = "#id")
public Item updateItem(Integer id, Item request) {
    Item item = getItem(id);
    item.setPrice(request.getPrice());
    item.setProductName(request.getProductName());
    return itemRepository.save(item);
}
```

Once we start the application, The first request goes to the database. And the subsequent requests fetch data from the Redis cache-store. We know this because,

The logs says the records is from the database.

```
c.s.e.s.cache.service.ItemService:Loading data from DB Item{id=2,productName='Pants Large',price=21.99}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as RedisConfiguration, For JedisCluster Mode= enabled, you can also replace this with RedisStandalone for single instance

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisClientConfig;
import redis.clients.jedis.HostAndPort;
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster;
import sg.customs.ntp.rsrf.commonservice.util.JedisUtil;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.host:#{''}}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.port:#{6379}}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${spring.redis.jedis.pool.max-active-connections:#{8}}")
    private int maxActive;

    @Value("${spring.redis.jedis.pool.max-idle:#{4}}")
    private int maxIdle;

    @Value("${spring.redis.jedis.pool.min-idle:#{1}}")
    private int minIdle;

    @Value("${spring.redis.cluster.max-attempts:#{10}}")
    private int maxAttempts;

    @PostConstruct
    public void getJedisClusterConfiguration() {
        HostAndPort hostAndPort = new HostAndPort(host, port);
        DefaultJedisClientConfig jedisClientConfig = DefaultJedisClientConfig.builder()
                .ssl(true)
                .build();
        GenericObjectPoolConfig<Jedis> genericObjectPoolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig<>();
        genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
        genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxActive);
        genericObjectPoolConfig.setMinIdle(minIdle);
        JedisUtil.setInstance(new JedisCluster(hostAndPort, jedisClientConfig, maxAttempts, genericObjectPoolConfig));
    }
}
```

and Use this as JedisUtil

```
import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster;
import redis.clients.jedis.params.SetParams;

@Slf4j
@UtilityClass
public class JedisUtil {
    private static JedisCluster jedisCluster;

    public static void setInstance(JedisCluster cluster) {
        jedisCluster = cluster;
    }

    public void set(String key, String value) {
        try {
            jedisCluster.set(key, value);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    public void set(String key, String value, long timeToLive) {
        try {
            jedisCluster.set(key, value, new SetParams().ex(timeToLive));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        try {
            return jedisCluster.get(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void del(String key) {
        try {
            jedisCluster.del(key);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```